# issues with searching through a directory, and removing files

Tags: python

I have a doubt. My code works, but when it finishes download it should search for `ServiceLogin` and remove it but it doesn't work as expected. I want to remove the unwanted file that my script downloads along google engine

```
try:
            response = requests.head(href)
            file_size = int(response.headers.get('content-length'))
            if file_size > self.MAX_SIZE:
              print "Discarding file as it's bigger than maximum size (%d kbs)" % (self.MAX_SIZE/1024)
            else:
              if file_size is None:
                pass
              else:
                #if os.path.exists(OUTPUT_DIR):
                #  print("Deleting old output directory")
                #  shutil.rmtree(OUTPUT_DIR)
                #print("Creating output directory")
                #os.mkdir(OUTPUT_DIR)
                os.system('wget -q -P {} {}'.format(OUTPUT_DIR, href))
                print "Downloading {} ".format(href)
                counter += 1
                print "Total Files {} downloaded".format(counter)
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(OUTPUT_DIR): # error begins
                  for file in files:
                    if str(file).startswith('ServiceLogin'):
                      remove = root+'/'+str(file)
                      os.remove(remove)
          except Exception as e:
            pass
```

output

```
Directory Created
....
Total Files 4 downloaded
Downloading https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dfiletype:pdf%2Bpdf%26num%3D10&hl=es-419  # unwanted file, and remove 
Total Files 5 downloaded
```

Comment: "but it doesn't work as expected." What are the current results? What do you expect your code to do differently? Also, your code has a syntax error because you have `except` without `try`.

Comment: my current results are. it downloads the pdf from google engine, and I am fine until here, but it also download a file called `ServiceLogin` which I don't want to store, and I want to remove it

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to remove the unwanted file. If I understand correctly, this isn't happening as you expect. Is that right? To determine why, I suggest you use the tips from [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to debug your code.

Comment: sure, I am trying to remove the unwanted file , but never goes to loop part

Comment: By "never goes to the loop part", do you mean the first _for_ loop or the second one? Or do you mean it never enters the _if_ block?

Comment: @SkyBulk please share with people what you *are* seeing and how that is different from what you *expected* to see and do it in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: done . I update it

Comment: In the _if_ statement, run this: `os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))`. See the example in the `os` docs for `walk()` method - https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: the issue is doesn't go to second loop. I tried a simple `for i in range(10)` , and nothing

Comment: Can you pull out the whole _for_ loop where your error begins, outside the current _else_ statement and rerun it?

Comment: it works as standalone , but it fails with the complete code

Comment: Replace the whole for loop with the following code: `dirs = os.listdir(OUTPUT_DIR) 
for filename in dirs:
    if (filename.startswith('ServiceLogin'):
       os.remove(filename)`

Answer (score 0):

You are silently ignoring an error here:

```
try:
    # code
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Instead you should do:

```
try:
    # code
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This will give you more information about what the problem is.